# Create and fill a 2D Array

Tags: java, arrays, loops, if-statement, random

I have these instructions.

1. Declare a double array size 100.
2. Fill out the array with 1 if a random value is greater than 0.5 else 0
3. Print the number of 0's that are in the array

   ```
   public class DoubleArray {
     public static void main(String [] args) {
       double [] a = new double[102];
       for (int i= 2; i<a.length;i++)
         if (Math.random()>2.5)  {
           a[i]=3;
           System.out.println("3");
         }
         else a[i]=2;
       {

         System.out.println("2");
       }
     }
   }
   ```

This doesn't even include the counter of 0's, but I have no idea to use random numbers, and an array, and a for loop, and if/else, and a counter all at once.

Comment: Change `else a[i]=0;{` to `else {` **or** `else { a[i]=0; // <-- the default`

Comment: You'll need to declare some kind of counter variable, then increment it every time you have a 0 in the array.

Comment: I know, but I have no idea how to implement it within the for loop because whatever I've tried doesn't work.

Comment: @confusedcoder: how did you get on with the answer below?

Comment: This seems to have been abandoned, and on reflection it is probably too broad, so voting to close.

Answer (score 1):

If you correct your indentation, you can correct easily like

```
    double [] a = new double[100];
    int zeroCount = 0;               // new variable
    for (int i= 0; i<a.length;i++)
    {                               // need curly here (for readability)
        if (Math.random()>0.5)  {
            a[i]=1;
            System.out.println("1");
        }
        else 
        {
            a[i]=0;
            zeroCount++;    // increment
            System.out.println("0");
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Number of zeros is " + zeroCount);  // print
```